# ADF-Web Activity-The format of the URI could not be determined

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I can't figure out what is the problem and what should be done.
Nothing has been changed in the configuration of the web activity but still this error appears. I tried to convert it with conversion functions @dataUri, @dataUriToString, @string but it gives the same error.

"The format of the URI could not be determined.
Request didn't reach the server from the client. This could happen because of an underlying issue such as network connectivity, a DNS failure, a server certificate validation or a timeout."

[image: Invalid URI]

[image: @pipeline().RunId]

[image: web activity INPUT]

Thank you in advance,
BR

Comment: @pipeline().RunId gives you the Runid and I think it is String value not URl. Thats why it is giving error about The format of the URI. Could you please recheck on that.

Comment: I edited the question and added a picture with the Input where the URI is.

Comment: To which url are you trying to post the data? Could you please add any format of it?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, problem solved! The problem was related to the Logic app. 
For some reason the LogicApp has stopped and accordingly the files in the ADLS Gen2 container were not updated and due to this the pipeline run was stopping on the web activity. After updating the files in the container the pipeline passed successfully.